# Custom UITableViewCells (NIBS) Not Displaying In UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nib

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UINib *tNIb = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"textFieldNib" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:tNIb forCellReuseIdentifier:@"textCell"];

UINib *dNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"descriptionNib" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:dNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"descriptionCell"];

UINib *iNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"imageNib" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:iNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"];

UINib *lNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"labelNib" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:lNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"labelCell"];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", self.collegeString, self.presidentString, self.membersString);

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"   forIndexPath:indexPath];
_textCell = (textFieldCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"];
_descriptionCell = (descriptionCell *) [self.tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"descriptionCell"];
_imageCell = (imageCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"];
_labelCell = (labelCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"labelCell"];

if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    _labelCell.collegeLabel.text = self.collegeString;
    _labelCell.presidentLabel.text = self.presidentString;
    _labelCell.membersLabel.text = self.membersString;
    return _labelCell;
}
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    return _imageCell;
}
if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    return _descriptionCell;
}
if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    return _textCell;
}
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"Height for row called");
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    return 100.0f;
}
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    return 100.0f;
}
if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    return 130.0f;
}
if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    return 110.0f;
}
else{
    return 90.0f;
}

}
```

I have four different custom cells I made with nibs files and each paired with their own UITableViewCell .h/.m files. They each have a different size. I have no idea why the aren't displaying in the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        TextFieldCell *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"];
        ImageCell *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"];
        LabelCell *labelCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"labelCell"];

        if (textCell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"textFieldNib" owner:self options:nil];
            textCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
       if (imageCell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"imageCellNib" owner:self options:nil];
            imageCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
       if (labelCell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"labelCellNib" owner:self options:nil];
            labelCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }


      if (indexPath.section == 1) 
      {
            labelCell.collegeLabel.text = self.collegeString;
            labelCell.presidentLabel.text = self.presidentString;
            labelCell.membersLabel.text = self.membersString;
            return labelCell;
      }
     else if (indexPath.section == 2) 
      {
            return imageCell;
     }
     else if (indexPath.section == 3) 
     {
            return textCell;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

**This should be your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: {
            textFieldNib *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"
                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //set up textCell
            textCell.collegeLabel.text = self.collegeString;
            textCell.presidentLabel.text = self.presidentString;
            textCell.membersLabel.text = self.membersString;

            return textCell;
        }
        case 1: {
            descriptionNib *descriptionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"descriptionCell"
                                                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //set up descriptionCell

            return descriptionCell;
        }
        case 2: {
            imageNib *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"
                                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //set up imageCell

            return imageCell;
        }
        case 3: {
            labelNib *labelCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"labelCell"
                                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //set up labelCell

            return labelCell;
        }
        default: {
            //none of the cases worked so return default UITableViewCell to prevent crash
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Solution 2:

When you **don't** do `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` then load the nib in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: {
            textFieldNib *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"];
            if (textCell == nil) {
                textCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"textFieldNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
            }
            //set up textCell
            textCell.collegeLabel.text = self.collegeString;
            textCell.presidentLabel.text = self.presidentString;
            textCell.membersLabel.text = self.membersString;

            return textCell;
        }
        case 1: {
            descriptionNib *descriptionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"descriptionCell"];
            if (descriptionCell == nil) {
                descriptionCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"descriptionNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
            }

            //set up descriptionCell

            return descriptionCell;
        }
        case 2: {
            imageNib *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell"];
            if (imageCell == nil) {
                imageCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"imageNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
            }

            //set up imageCell

            return imageCell;
        }
        case 3: {
            labelNib *labelCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"labelCell"];
            if (labelCell == nil) {
                labelCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"labelNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
            }

            //set up labelCell

            return labelCell;
        }
        default: {
            //none of the cases worked so return default UITableViewCell to prevent crash
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

---

PS: Don't make global `UITableViewCell` objects like `_textCell` and `_descriptionCell` etc. It's just wasteful and frankly... useless for most purposes.